# Pandas: Create a column where row is equal to the row below in another column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, row

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[44,44,44,88,88,90,95],
               'Old Status': ['Draft','Submit','Return','Submit','Accept',
               'Draft','Draft'],
               'New Status' : ['Submit','Return','Reject','Accept','Develop',
                              'Submit','Reject'],
                              'Datetime': ['2018-10-24 08:12:02',
                              '2018-10-24 18:12:02', '2018-11-24 08:56:02',
                              '2018-10-24 10:12:02','2018-10-29 13:17:02',
                              '2018-12-30 08:43:12', '2019-01-24 06:12:02']
                              }, columns = ['id','Old Status', 'New Status', 'Datetime'])
df1['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Datetime'])                              
df1
   id Old Status New Status            Datetime
0  44      Draft     Submit 2018-10-24 08:12:02
1  44     Sumbit     Return 2018-10-24 18:12:02
2  44     Return     Reject 2018-11-24 08:56:02
3  88     Submit     Accept 2018-10-24 10:12:02
4  88     Accept    Develop 2018-10-29 13:17:02
5  90      Draft     Submit 2018-12-30 08:43:12
6  95      Draft     Reject 2019-01-24 06:12:02
```

I've got a dataframe in the above format, but I need to make things easier when visualizing the data so I need two columns, a 'Status In' and a 'Status Out' date. 'Status In' would be equal to the `Datetime.loc[n]` column, `Status Out` would equal `Datetime.loc[n+1]` for any `id`.

When the next row has a new `id`, this can be assumed the `New Status` is the current status, so `Status Out` would be `null`.

I've been researching around but can't seem to find any related questions on this. So I starting using a loop but it just feels ugly and I know there must be a more 'Pandas' way to do this.

So far I have the following. Then I plan to add conditionals to handle the `id`changes and then convert to a dataframe, but it feels so wrong:

```
df['Status In'] = df['Datetime']
s_out = [0]*(df['Status In'].count()-1)
for el in range(0,df['Status In'].count()-1):
    s_out[el] = df['Status In'].iloc[el+1]
```

The end result would look something like:

```
   id Old Status New Status           Status In           Status Out
0  44      Draft     Submit 2018-10-24 08:12:02  2018-10-24 18:12:02
1  44     Sumbit     Return 2018-10-24 18:12:02  2018-11-24 08:56:02
2  44     Return     Reject 2018-11-24 08:56:02                  NaN
3  88     Submit     Accept 2018-10-24 10:12:02  2018-10-29 13:17:02
4  88     Accept    Develop 2018-10-29 13:17:02                  NaN
5  90      Draft     Submit 2018-12-30 08:43:12                  NaN
6  95      Draft     Reject 2019-01-24 06:12:02                  NaN
```

Is there a better, cleaner way to do this in Python/Pandas without using for loops and if-statements?

Comment: Will the id column always be sorted?

Comment: Sorting by datetime:  `2  44     Sumbit      Draft 2018-10-24 08:12:02` -- > `1  44      Draft     Submit 2018-10-24 18:12:02` -- > `0  44     Reject      Draft 2018-11-24 08:56:02`. I can't make sense of the timeline at all. The time stamps are running backwards to the events?

Comment: @roganjosh I've edited the df to fix timeline/events, @Dallas Lindauer, it doesn't always need to be sorted on `id` no, when it comes to visualizing the important thing to see all n `id` in a `New Status` at a given point in time. But for checking/readability it is just preferred to have it sorted on `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) first and then [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) by mask by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
shifted = df1.groupby('id')['Datetime','Old Status'].shift(-1)
print (shifted)
             Datetime Old Status
0 2018-10-24 18:12:02     Submit
1 2018-11-24 08:56:02     Return
2                 NaT        NaN
3 2018-10-29 13:17:02     Accept
4                 NaT        NaN
5                 NaT        NaN
6                 NaT        NaN

df1['Status Out'] = shifted['Datetime'].where(df1['New Status'].eq(shifted['Old Status']))
print (df1)
   id Old Status New Status            Datetime          Status Out
0  44      Draft     Submit 2018-10-24 08:12:02 2018-10-24 18:12:02
1  44     Submit     Return 2018-10-24 18:12:02 2018-11-24 08:56:02
2  44     Return     Reject 2018-11-24 08:56:02                 NaT
3  88     Submit     Accept 2018-10-24 10:12:02 2018-10-29 13:17:02
4  88     Accept    Develop 2018-10-29 13:17:02                 NaT
5  90      Draft     Submit 2018-12-30 08:43:12                 NaT
6  95      Draft     Reject 2019-01-24 06:12:02                 NaT
```